# How to connect the ESP8266 and DHT11 to arduino Uno?

Tags: esp8266

I am new to the IoT. I am doing a project which includes collection of weather information and send data to the thingspeak.
I struggled for the connection of **ESP8266** to **Arduino Uno** . Finally its responding to the AT commands in the serial monitor. But when I completely wrote those commands in a file and try to upload it into the Arduino, I am receiving an error.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true
#define RX 0
#define TX 1

String TCP="TCP";
String HOST = "api.thingspeak.com";
String PORT = "80";
String AP = "Phani";
String PASS = "Nani8125297382";


String API = "M5VZGOK12OC13E7G";
String field = "field1";

int countTrueCommand;
int countTimeCommand; 
boolean found = false; 
int valSensor = 1;

SoftwareSerial esp8266(RX,TX); 
void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);
esp8266.begin(115200);

sendCommand("AT",5,"OK");
sendCommand("AT+CWMODE=1",5,"OK");
sendCommand("AT+CWJAP=""+ AP +"",""+ PASS +""",15,"OK");
countTrueCommand = 0;

}

void loop() {

String getData = "GET /update?api_key="+ API +"&"+ field +"="+String(valSensor);
switch(countTrueCommand) {

case 0: sendCommand("AT",5,"OK");break;
case 1: sendCommand("AT+RST",10,"invalid");break;
case 2: sendCommand("AT+CIPMUX=1",5,"OK"); break;
case 3: sendCommand("AT+CIPSTART=0,"+TCP+","+ HOST +","+ PORT,15,"OK"); break;
case 4: sendCommand("AT+CIPSEND=0," +String(getData.length()+4),4,">"); break;
case 5: esp8266.println(getData);delay(1500);countTrueCommand++; break;
case 6: sendCommand("AT+CIPCLOSE=0",5,"OK"); break;
case 7:

Serial.println(valSensor);
Serial.print(getData);
Serial.print(",");
Serial.println(getData.length());
valSensor = random(100000); // random value, change with sensor value if using sensor
countTrueCommand = 0;
delay(10000);
break;

}

}
void sendCommand(String command, int maxTime, char readReplay[]) {

Serial.print(countTrueCommand);
Serial.print(". at command => ");
Serial.print(command);
Serial.print(" ");
while(countTimeCommand < (maxTime*1))

{

esp8266.println(command);//at+cipsend
if(esp8266.find(readReplay))//ok
{

found = true;
break;

}
countTimeCommand++;

}
if(found == true)
{

Serial.println("OYI");

countTrueCommand++;
countTimeCommand = 0;

}
if(found == false)
{

Serial.println("Fail");
countTrueCommand = 0;
countTimeCommand = 0;

}
found = false;

}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
avrdude: Version 6.3-20171130
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware\tools\avr/etc/avrdude.conf"

         Using Port                    : COM6
         Using Programmer              : arduino
         Overriding Baud Rate          : 115200
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x45
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfc
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x45
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfc
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x45
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfc
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x45
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfc
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x8a
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xfc

avrdude done.  Thank you.

An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

I don't understand how to do. Can anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: have you tried uploading a different sketch?

Comment: the  ESP8266 is interfering with the serial port ..... disconnect it while uploading the sketch

Comment: Yes, it got uploaded. But i dont know , i am getting fail. As per the program, it is going to case 0.

Comment: You may do better asking this on the Arduino stack exchange

Comment: If i am testing esp8266 from a serial monitor by sending AT commands , its connecting and its responding successfully. But when I am using it in a program i could not make it successfull as i am really very new to this concept.